# Error calling activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Nothing shows at LogCat, so i have no ideia of the error, hero goes the entire code:

```
package com.ibssistemas.pda;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ibssistemas.pda.database.dbHelper;

public class BuscaCliente extends Activity {
ListView lista;
public void AtualizaLista(String nome) {
    dbHelper DB = new dbHelper(BuscaCliente.this);
    SQLiteDatabase dB = DB.getReadableDatabase();
    if (nome == null) {
        Cursor c = dB.query("Cliente", (new String[]{"cdCliente", "nmCliente", "cdCPFCNPJ"}), null, null, null, null, "cdCliente");
        if (c.getCount()==0) {
            Toast.makeText(BuscaCliente.this, "Nenhum cliente encontrado!", 10).show();
            return;
        }
        c.moveToFirst();
        String[] from = {"cdCliente", "nmCliente", "cdCPFCNPJ"};
        int[] to = {R.id.cdCliente,R.id.nmCliente, R.id.CPFCliente};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(BuscaCliente.this, R.layout.layoutbuscacliente, c, from, to);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        dB.close();
        return;
    }
    nome = nome.toUpperCase();
    Cursor c = dB.query("Cliente", (new String[]{"cdCliente", "nmCliente", "cdCPFCNPJ"}), "nmCliente LIKE \"%"+nome+"%\"", null, null, null, "cdCliente");
    if (c.getCount()==0) {
        Toast.makeText(BuscaCliente.this, "Nenhum cliente encontrado!", 10).show();
        return;
    }
    c.moveToFirst();
    String[] from = {"cdCliente", "nmCliente", "cdCPFCNPJ"};
    int[] to = {R.id.cdCliente,R.id.nmCliente, R.id.CPFCliente};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(BuscaCliente.this, R.layout.layoutbuscacliente, c, from, to);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    dB.close();
    return;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buscacliente);
    lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaBuscaCliente);
    AtualizaLista(null);

}

}
```

Comment: It's difficult to say what might be the problem if you have no logcat output (as you've found). It might be a good idea to single-step in the debugger to identify the problem line, and then update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with most of the comments, but as I see you call with nome==null...
Your error must be here:

```
dbHelper DB = new dbHelper(BuscaCliente.this);
SQLiteDatabase dB = DB.getReadableDatabase();
```

For any reason it seems you can't connect to database, because the other code is clear. Try also to add a try/catch block and log the exception details.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you instantiate nome. Therefore you would get a NPE error on this line:

```
 nome = nome.toUpperCase();
```

Your LogCat should show this though, so maybe something else is going wrong first. You really need to debug step through your code and work it out.

Comment: nome is an argument to AtualizaLista and nome.toUpper is never called if nome == null

Comment: nome is passed in as null. Ah yes he returns out the if, would of been clearer as an else.

Comment: I agree it could be clearer, and under the circumstances, I'd probably have two overloaded versions - one with a String argument, and one with a void argument.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others.  When I see a problem like this one thing I often do is insert Log.d() statements in the code.  Then I look to see what is the last one that fires.  The step method in the debugger might be easier for you though.  Since you have no logcat output, how do you know that the activity is erroring out?   What is the app doing?

Comment: The app just crashes when i try to open the screen.

Comment: JL sorry I missed your comment here.  If it's crashing on open there should be an error in your logcat.  If not I would recommend using Debugger to step through the code to figure out where it dies. You would want to set a breakpoint first thing in the activity so it will pause.